# Configure Solr to index metadata included in seed.txt

Tags: solr, field, metadata, nutch

I am currently running Nutch 1.10 and solr 5.3.1, and I am attempting to crawl and index a few sites.  These sites have an id and name associated (on the same line as the url in the seed.txt file) which I would like to be included along side other fields in the solr search results (such as host, segment, etc).  Is this possible? If so, would I need to modify any files other than the seed.txt and schema-solr4?

Example of what I have in seed.txt:

www.exampleSite.com       id=3         name=exampleSite